# Why doesn't this work?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

I'v tried to solve a memory leak in the GLU callback by creating a global variable but now it dos not draw anything:

```
GLdouble *gluptr = NULL;

void CALLBACK combineCallback(GLdouble coords[3], GLdouble *vertex_data[4],
                              GLfloat weight[4], GLdouble **dataOut)
{
    GLdouble *vertex;
    if(gluptr == NULL)
    {
        gluptr = (GLdouble *) malloc(6 * sizeof(GLdouble));
    }
    vertex = (GLdouble*)gluptr;
    vertex[0] = coords[0];
    vertex[1] = coords[1];
    vertex[2] = coords[2];


    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
    {

        vertex[i] = weight[0] * vertex_data[0][i] +
            weight[1] * vertex_data[0][i] +
            weight[2] * vertex_data[0][i] +
            weight[3] * vertex_data[0][i];
    }


    *dataOut = vertex;


}
```

basically instead of doing malloc each time in the loop (thus the memory leak) im using a global pointer, but this doesn't work (drawing to the screen not working) which means dataOut is not receiving the vertex data pointed to by my pointer. Why would using malloc to a pointer created in the function work any different than a global variable?

Thanks

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* isn't a helpful description - what doesn't work?

Comment: basically why was it drawing before but not anymore?

Comment: Why is there a cast here? `vertex = (GLdouble*)gluptr;`?

Comment: now that I understand it I just used a vector of pointers then free them all, thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate the data only once -- but GLUtesselator needs more than one set of data at a time!

What you do here, is putting all the vertex data into a single place in memory, where in the original code, you had memory per vertex. GLUtesselator needs more then one vertex to function properly.

You **do** call

```
void gluDeleteTess(GLUtesselator *tessobj);
```

...afterwards, do you?

Comment: GLUtesselator, if it's written correctly, should free the memory when it's finished with it (or give it back to you somehow for freeing). That is the prime directive when passing around pointers - whoever "owns" the pointer has responsibility for freeing it.

Comment: @paxdiablo, you beat me to it :P

Comment: Ah, yes, but you appear to have _specific_ knowledge (whereas mine is just general knowledge of "how things work") so +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the reason is that something outside of your callback is holding on to the returned data across calls to combineCallback(), and subsequent calls to combineCallback() clobber now the data from the older calls.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, you need to rewrite this, there's a few things wrong which shows the inherent lack of understanding pointers and using call-by-reference parameter such as `dataOut`, secondly, there is no checking on the call to `malloc` which can fail and **WILL** fail, the code blindly assumes that the memory is available, thirdly, you have redundant pointer variables used such as `vertex` and `gluptr` for a reason. You are actually trying to build up a block of memory by copying the contents from `gluptr` to `vertex`, and use the `coords` pointer-to-block of data type of 'GLDouble', then build up the `vertex` block of memory... and finally assign it back to `dataOut`...forgive me if I misunderstand but read on...

This is the code that has removed redundant variables as shown below and fixes up the lack of checking for a NULL pointer...

```
GLdouble *gluptr = NULL;

void CALLBACK combineCallback(GLdouble coords[3], GLdouble *vertex_data[4],
                              GLfloat weight[4], GLdouble **dataOut)
{
    if((*dataOut) == NULL)
    {
        (*dataOut) = (GLdouble *) malloc(6 * sizeof(GLdouble));
    }
    if (*dataOut != NULL){
       /* PASSED MEMORY ALLOC! */
       (*dataOut)[0] = coords[0];
       (*dataOut)[1] = coords[1];
       (*dataOut)[2] = coords[2];

       for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
       {

        (*dataOut)[i] = weight[0] * vertex_data[0][i] +
            weight[1] * vertex_data[0][i] +
            weight[2] * vertex_data[0][i] +
            weight[3] * vertex_data[0][i];
       }
    }
}
```

The last parameter when calling this function `combineCallback` is a call-by-reference parameter, hence the usage of the double asterisk..

I must ask this, is `dataOut` definitely a fixed size of 6 elements? if so then the parameter would need to be tweaked up...to make it look like `*(*dataOut[6])`... looking at it top off my head (*it's late and past my bedtime...*)